# How to convert AnsiString into an Integer in modern Delphi?

Tags: string, delphi, unicode, type-conversion

*This is a little different from `SameText` question.*

I need to convert `AnsiString` into an `Integer`.

```
var
  param: AnsiString;
  num: Integer;
begin
  if TryStrToInt(param, num) then
  ...
```

In pre-Unicode Delphi I would use `TryStrToInt` function, but in modern Delphi there is only Unicode version of it, so I'm getting this warning: W1057 Implicit string cast from 'AnsiString' to 'string' upon call.

My question is, how to properly convert AnsiStrings in modern Delphi without getting compiler warnings (and without superfluously having to cast string to UnicodeString(text))

Comment: A comment for you. You are not expected to use `UnicodeString` in your code. Standard practise is to use its alias, `string`. Not that the declaration of `TryStrToInt` uses `string` rather than `UnicodeString`. So the explicit cast should be `string(param)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Various options are available to you:

1. Accept and embrace Unicode. Stop using `AnsiString`.
2. Use an explicit conversion to `string`: `TryStrToInt(string(param), num)`.
3. Disable warning W1057.
4. Perform the conversion from ANSI to UTF-16 yourself with a call to `MultiByteToWideChar`. This isn't a serious option, but if you want to leave W1057 enabled, and not use an explicit conversion, then it's what is left.

Frankly, option 1 is to be preferred. If you try to persist the use of `AnsiString` through your code you will be wallowing in an endless morass of casts and warnings. If you have a need for ANSI encoded strings it is likely to be at an interop boundary. Perhaps you are reading or writing files that use ANSI encoding. Perform the conversion between ANSI and UTF-16 at the interop boundary. The rest of the time, for your internal code, use `string`.

Comment: I'm using AnsiStrings to separate certain things from mixing with other UnicodeStrings intentionally, so that compiler gives me a warning when that happens by mistake. I'm using verbose types because of serialization and backwrads compatibility.

Comment: OK, if you cannot use 1, and you must have W1057 enabled, then you are looking at options 2 or 4 above.

Comment: Thank you. I was just hoping to get something alike `AnsiStrings.SameText` kind of thing here.

Comment: Why are you concerned about converting to UTF-16. So long as your start with ANSI data, you can convert to and from in a lossless fashion.

Comment: My code is from gamedev and I'm kinda used to avoiding unnecessary conversions. Looks like I'm picking option 2 for now.

Comment: If you carry on in this vein you'll probably end up with more conversions that if you went for option 1.

Comment: Probably, but those extra conversions help me to detect bugs.

Comment: No, what I mean is that if you converted at the boundary, then you'd do the conversion once only. As it is you are proposing to do the conversion multiple times. It's no more or less buggy.

Comment: Thing is, certain areas are set to be using only ANSI Latin characters. Now if I use AnsiString for those, each time they leak into other areas where general strings are used - I get a compiler warning.

Comment: You know your problem domain, I don't. So I can only give you general advice based on my own experience. So, if ANSI makes sense in your domain, do it.

Comment: I don't see why. I think that they add value for other readers.

Answer (score 0):

> how to properly convert AnsiStrings in modern Delphi without getting
>   compiler warnings (and without superfluously having to cast string to
>   UnicodeString

If you don't cast from AnsiString to String, the compiler will do it for you. You can't avoid the cast. It's just a matter if you explicitly do it, or the compiler does it for you implicitly.

When you explicitly do the conversion in code (via cast), then the compiler doesn't worry about the side effects. It assumes you know what you're doing and leaves you alone.

You'll have to choose one. Compiler warning or explicit casting.

You could technically turn those compiler warnings off (but don't do this):

> W1057     IMPLICIT_STRING_CAST    ON  Implicit string cast from ‘%s’ to
>   ‘%s’ (Delphi)
>
> W1058     IMPLICIT_STRING_CAST_LOSS   ON  Implicit string cast with
>   potential data loss from ‘%s’ to ‘%s’ (Delphi)

Comment: Another solution would be to have dedicated `TryStrToIntA` or something alike perhaps

Comment: @KromStern, good point. If you're calling one function repeatedly, wrap it up.

Comment: Actually, I turn off `W1057`, but leave `W1058` on.